# How to use history.go(-1) Javascript when used in alert box for a jQuery mobile app build via phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, dom-events

Actually, I am trying to check for internet connection and if there is no internet connection available then I am popping an alert box showing Sorry, Can't display data and on user pressing the ok button, I want to transfer him back to the home page of my app.

My current Javascript function is as follows, but its not working as expected.

```
   function showerror(){
      alert("Sorry, Check your Internet Connection. Going Back to the Home page. showerror()");   
      history.go(-1);
      }
```

Please any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried with `history.back()`, this will go only one level back though

Comment: Why do you want to send user back to your homepage if there is no connection? Also, if you want to send the user to a specific page, do this: `location.href = "http://yoursite.com/";`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `navigator.notification.alert` method to show a device specific alert with a callback when the dialog is closed. Then use `history.back()` to send the user to the previous page.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert

Example:

```
function showerror() {
  navigator.notification.alert(
    'Sorry, Check your Internet Connection. Going Back to the Home page. showerror()',
    function() {
      history.back();
    }
  );
}
```

**Edit:**

If you know the specific page to return to you could always use `$.mobile.changePage` to go to that page. The only issue is when running on devices with a back button (Android, WP7).

Example:

```
function showerror() {
  navigator.notification.alert(
    'Sorry, Check your Internet Connection. Going Back to the Home page. showerror()',
    function() {
      $.mobile.changePage('#homePage');
    }
  );
}
```